# /usr/bin/env: ‘awk -f’: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, awk, shebang

Linux shylock-archinux 4.15.15-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Mar 31 23:59:25 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My machine is above.Anyone know what happend?

The script with shebang `#! /usr/bin/env awk -f` don't work?I call it by `./script.awk inputfile`,it should be same as manually call `awk -f ./script.awk inputfile`,but only the latter work well!

`which awk` output `/usr/bin/awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shebang line typically only takes at most two arguments, so it's considering `"awk -f"` as a single argument to `env`.

Considering you know the path to your `awk`, using that directly should fix the problem for you:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304187/9447571 for a few more details on how shebang arguments are recognized.